# One onAnimationUpdate listener for some ValueAnimator-s

Tags: android

I'm trying to use `ValueAnimator` to generate values from different ranges at one time.

For example, first `ValueAnimator` generate values from the range of floats [0.3, 0.8], second from the range [0.9, 0.65] etc with one duration.

And I need a listener like `onAnimationUpdate` which would take values from every ValueAnimator.
In our case it has to take 4 float values.

I saw `AnimatorSet` class which has the method `playTogether` and can take `ValueAnimator` objects. But it hasn't any single listener for all objects.
Maybe there's some solution with these classes or there's another approach for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I just used one `ValueAnimator`.
In `onAnimationUpdate` listener method I just get current fraction via `getAnimatedFraction` method and apply it for every my range of floats.

So if we for example have the next two ranges of floats (`[0.3f, 1.0f]` and `[0.1f, 0.4f]`) then after half the time elapsed set with `setDuration` we have fraction about 0.5 and we use it to calculate our values for every range.

```
float curValueInFirstRange = 0.3f + (1.0f - 0.3f) * curFraction;
```

etc ..